# Rounded Corner Bottom TextView inside CardView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design, android-cardview

I am using CardView to show List Items, where each and every List Item contains two textviews, namely - BOOK NOW/BOOK and DETAIL/DETAILS.

I would like to achieve rounded bottom TextView, but getting in rectangular shape

[image]

I have to design something like this:

[image]

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                .......

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/more"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btnBook"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="BOOK"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btnDetail"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="DETAILS"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:gravity="center" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

*Where I have to make change to get it done ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set this background to the `LinearLayout` containing the `textViews`

```
<item>    
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="cardview_corner_radius_value"
                android:bottomRightRadius="cardview_corner_radius_value" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

and add `background` of `TextView` as transparent

Answer (score 1):

You have to make selector for this in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
      <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/more" />
            <dotted android:color="#00FF0000" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp"/>
        </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then set background to your view. Use this

```
android:background="@drawable/corner_selector"
```

instead of

```
android:background="@color/more"
```

Answer (score 1):

make a file `rounded_border.xml` in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >         
<stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="@color/common_border_color" />

<solid android:color="#fff" />

<padding
       android:left="1dp"
       android:right="1dp"
       android:top="1dp" />

<corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

and keep it as a background of linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_border"
            android:layout_weight="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     1. make button.xml file and put it in drawable folder
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:state_pressed="true" >
         <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
             <corners android:radius="3dip" />
             <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
             <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#345953" android:endColor="#689a92"  />            
         </shape>
     </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
         <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
             <corners android:radius="3dip" />
             <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
             <solid android:color="#58857e"/>       
         </shape>
     </item>  
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
             <corners android:radius="3dip" />
             <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
             <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#8dbab3" android:endColor="#58857e" />            
         </shape>
     </item>
    </selector>
2. then change your xml background of Linearlayout 
 android:background="@color/more"
to 
android:background="@drawable/button"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this simplest way to do this your Layout
[image: here are the pic for example]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btnbackground"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:text="My Profile"
    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

after that make a xml in drawable folder btnbackground.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/llabeforeclick3" 
    android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/llaafterclick3"/>

</selector>
```

then make another llabeforeclick3.xml in drawable directory

```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#19384A" >
    </solid>

     <corners
     android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
     android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
     android:topRightRadius="10dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="10dp" /> 

 <stroke
    android:width="0dp"
    android:color="#19384A" /> 

<padding
    android:left="4dp"
    android:top="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:color="#19384A" />     
</shape>
```

after that make another xml llaafterclick3.xml in drawable

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle" >
     //background color

    <solid android:color="#204A60" >
    </solid>

  <corners
     android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
     android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
     android:topRightRadius="10dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="10dp" />
        //before clicked

  <gradient
     android:angle="45"
     android:centerColor="#204A60"
     android:centerX="20"
     android:centerY="20"
     android:endColor="#204A60"
     android:gradientRadius="25"
     android:startColor="#204A60" />

</shape>
```

if some buddy wants to make more rounded corners then use to increase size of

```
     android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
     android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
     android:topRightRadius="10dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
```

That solve here your color code is depends on you you need to put color code only and radious.